# String concatenation bad order with DOM variable

Tags: javascript, string, google-maps, dom, concatenation

The context is the following: I am coding a webpage geolocalising people from an association and display their positions on a google map within a wordpress framework. When I click on their marker I display an info window with their info. On the map, I can filter/search the people with a form (for example look only at the people named Paul). So far all this working.

My problem is the following: When I do a search I would like to display the results underneath the map. As I can have quite a few results (let's say typically around 100) , I'ld like to display them with some pagination. I manage to use the paginator when I hardcode some dummy text. Nevertheless I can't manage to paginate the results of the searches.
If I do

```
<div id="pagination"></div>
<table id="content">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        Paul
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        John
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        Richard
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        George
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var items = $("#content tbody tr");
        var numItems = items.length;
        var perPage = 5;
        items.slice(perPage).hide();
        $("#pagination").pagination({
            items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
            cssStyle: "light-theme",
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {                             
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
                items.hide() 
                     .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working but if I try to dynamically write the html of "content" reading the attribute name of my markers like this:

```
var pag_res = "";   
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "";
for (mark_cnt = 0; mark_cnt < markers.length; mark_cnt++){
    pag_res += "<tbody><tr>" + markers[mark_cnt].desc + "</tbody></tr>";
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = pag_res;
```

This is not working and if I look into at document.getElementById('content').innerHTML in the console the description of the marker is written after the closure of the tbody. I have something like:
    
        
        
    
    Paul
    
        
        
    
    John

Anyone would have any idea where the issue stems from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be able to fix the problem by editing this line:

```
pag_res += "<tbody><tr>" + markers[mark_cnt].desc + "</tbody></tr>";
```

The last two tags are the wrong way around... it should be:

```
pag_res += "<tbody><tr>" + markers[mark_cnt].desc + "</tr></tbody>";
```

While you're there, you could tidy your HTML a bit, too. A table should only have one  and you're missing your  tags... it should be more like:

```
<table>
<tbody id="content">
    <tr>
        <td>Paul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Richard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>George</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that I've moved the id="content" onto the ... you'd then need to tweak the code to look like:

```
pag_res += "<tr><td>" + markers[mark_cnt].desc + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I do look silly for sure now :D I believe my fondamental mistake is that I was erase the id of the table when I was changing it's html. It is much clearer and tidier now.